# SubString matching using Regex

Tags: c++, regex

Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
    string s = "abc1010101bca10";
    int c = 0;
    string subject(s);
    try {
        regex re("10+1");
        sregex_iterator next(subject.begin(), subject.end(), re);
        sregex_iterator end;
        while (next != end) {
            smatch match = *next;
            cout << match.str() << "\n";
            c++;
            next++;
        }
    }
    catch (std::regex_error& e) {
        cout << "Error in regex\n";
    }
    cout << c << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to find the occurrence of **1{0}+1** in my string.

For input :  `abc1010101bca10`

Output count should be 3 but above code gives it as 2.

I think `sregex_iterator` causing problem here as it directly skips matched string.

Current output:

```
101
101
2
```

It should be: `101 101 101 3`

Please let me know, where I am going wrong.

Comment: A regular expression shouldn't match the same part of a string multiple times. This is the expected behavior and how all regex engines I'm aware of work. See, e.g.: this example on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/u1jGN2/1

Answer (score -1):

The output should be 2. Look at how the regular exprssion applies. The first match is

abc**101**0101bca10

the text **after** the first match is

0101bca10

so the next match is the "101" in that fragment, which, in the original text, is

abc1010**101**bca10

Comment: I believe OP is asking for overlapping matches.